# Overlay not covering entire background image only on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, google-chrome-devtools, responsive-images

In the mobile version of my website, the #l-splash background image takes up the whole viewpoint. I have a transparent overlay that goes on top of the background image. For some reason, the overlay doesn't cover the whole image, shown when you scroll down.

Shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHHD2.jpg

The overlay shows up fine in the Chrome dev tools, but when I bring the site up on an actual mobile device, it doesn't work. You can try yourself on your phone: https://nguyentrav.github.io/rice-paper/

I've tried tinkering with the heights of #l-splash and the #overlay-filter but had no luck.

https://jsfiddle.net/6aury4t5/3/

```css
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [content] minmax(0,1fr) [images] minmax(0,1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.content, .images {
  display: contents;
}

#l-splash {
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526069631228-723c945bea6b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80");
  height: 100vh; 
  width: 100%;
  position: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom center;
}

#overlay-filter {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) { 
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: [content] 100%;
  } 

  header, .images {
    display: none;
  }

  #overlay-filter {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 200%;
    height: 220%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background: rgb(172,172,172, 0.75);
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="content">

     <div id= "splash-container">

        <div id="overlay-filter"></div>

        <div id = "l-splash"></div>

     </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the overlay to cover the whole entire background responsively on any mobile device.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!